# Silverstripe Advancedwrokflow with DataObject not showing button

Tags: silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe (version 3.1.6) with advancedworkflow addon.

My site is build mostly on data objects.
I have assigned both object and model admin in the .yml file as described in the documentation:

```
MyObject:
    extensions:
        - WorkflowApplicable
MyObjectAdmin:
    extensions:
        - AdvancedWorkflowExtension
```

I have also assign the workflow in the workflow tab of the object.
I am using the template review and approve workflow.

While I see the button to start a workflow when editing a page, the button doesn't show up for the dataobject. Do I need to add code in the object level, or modify the template workflow to work with data objects?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you see the buttons after saving the dataobject ?

Comment: Digging dipper into the code, on 

advancedworkflow/code/extensions/WrokflowApplicable.php

on line 135 the function public function updateCMSActions(FieldList $actions) {
is not called on dataobjects but called on pages. this is the funciton that adds the button I believe. does this help anybody to understand the problem?

Comment: Just to give an update: I have filed an issue in github, and there is a bug in the addon. the guys at silverstripe are great and very diligent. they have great support and already working on a fix.
here is a link to the issue: https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/advancedworkflow/issues/202

Comment: @TomerAlmog, looking at the issue you raised on Github, it seems to be resolved. It probably is worth you answering your own question stating that the issue is resolved and maybe how it is (linking to the right bits in the PR mentioned in Github), also tying in any other important parts that you needed to do to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a happy to announce that the awesome SilverStripe team who wrote this addon resolved the issue (in the same day!!!)

for the code commit info please view:
https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/advancedworkflow/commit/38c5480e6b5c9a6856938ca774f2caf2790a788d

the changes are now part of the master branch, so I assume no one else will face this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of work for/on this module but rarely done anything with regard to Workflows and DataObjects - however - I do recall you need to make your custom DataObjects "Workflow aware", try the following in `mysite/_config/config.yml`

```
MyCustomeDataObject:
  extensions:
    - WorkflowApplicable
```

...and then run `dev/build`.

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. I have done that and did run dev/build.
I also saw the changes in the database as a result. but the initial action button is still missing...

Answer (score 1):

If you have overridden the getCMSFields() method in your DataObject but you don't use scaffolding (by calling fields=parent::getCMSFields()), you need to ensure that you call 'updateCMSFields' so the WorkflowApplicable extension can do its thing

```
public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = new FieldList();
    ...
    $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did use $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

Comment: There is that note for dataObject#getCMSActions()
"need to be overload by solid dataobject, so that the customised actions of that dataobject, including that dataobject's extensions customised actions could be added to the EditForm."

So you might need to do that in your custom dataobject:
    public function getCMSActions(){
        $actions = parent::getCMSActions();
        $this->extend('updateCMSActions', $actions);
 return $actions;
    }

Comment: Thank you!

Can you please explain what should be in that function or send a link to that reference?

Comment: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/model/DataObject.php#L2070

Comment: This is just the general implementation of a dataobject. the problem is in the advancedworkflow addon...